Why do my shadows look weird here? I applied smooth shading and marked the sharp edges as sharp
As the title said, these weird jagged shadows keep appearing all over my mesh. I already tried using auto smooth, normal smooth, and marking them as sharp and fixing the normals.
Here's the blend file just in case
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ls65H27Y-NIw5jLAXMC0vWGHrDk3Wt3f/view?usp=sharing


Could you try to "Clear Custom Split Normals Data" ? In Properties Editor (right panel by default), open Object Data Properties > Geometry Data.

@StefLAncien Thank you so much!!
